# HTML Code Is Not Rendering Properly

Tags: iphone, html

I'm having problems with my HTML and jQuery Code.  I was wondering if someone could tell me what's wrong with it.  Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title>Main Page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.css" />
    <!-- Color Scheme -->
    <!-- Beige: #eee8cd; Green: #008b8b; Blue: #203471; -->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="MainPage" style="background:#008b8b;color:#203471" data-role="page">
        <div style="background:#008b8b;color:#203471" data-role="content">
            <p style="background:#008b8b;color:#203471"><img alt="" src="Images/Header.png" style="width:100%" /></p>
            <p style="background:#008b8b;color:#eee8cd">The content for the main page is here</p>
            <a style="background:#eee8cd;color:#203471" href="AboutUs.htm" data-role="button">About Us</a>
            <a style="background:#eee8cd;color:#203471" href="ContactUs.htm" data-role="button">Contact Us</a>
        </div>
        <div style="background:#203471;color:#eee8cd" data-role="footer">
            <h4>Main Page Footer</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

There are two problems that I am having problems figuring out:

1) When I put this code on my web server and navigate to it via my iPhone it is fine when the phone is held in the vertical position.  When the phone is moved into the horizontal position though, the buttons seem to be displayed over the text and are not workable.  Any ideas on how to resolve this?

2)  I tried to create a custom stylesheet.css and link to it via the class attribute of the various tags.  This would not work so I had to put the inline code (for example:)

```
<div style="background:#203471;color:#eee8cd"
```

Can someone show me how to create a stylesheet.css with these attributes and "tag" them in the HTML so that this works?

Thanks So Much.

Comment: Complete a CSS tutorial, please.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kVqWJ/ play with the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Well, you've got a link to jQuery where your link to your CSS should go. Check out www.codecademy.com !

Comment: Can you link to two .css files in one HTML page?

Comment: Yes, but you usually don't want to do this. CSS was made to be able to be applied from a variety of points, you can use inline CSS, CSS in <style> tags in the head and multiple separate CSS documents all on the same HTML page. But if you have rules that contradict each other, the inline CSS takes precedent. In the beginning, in my opinion, you should have all your CSS in a separate file, and only have one of these files.

Answer (score 0):

I've separated inline css to its own and seems to render fine.

Play with this fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/kVqWJ/

You can include css files in your html file many ways:

```
1)

<style type="text/css">
//your style here
</style>

2) 

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css url here">
```

A quick googling will help. The [Mozilla developer network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) is a great place to start.

Comment: Any idea why it will not render properly on my iPhone in horizontal mode?